# Assume $G$ is a PRG. Proof that $G'$ is PRG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

> Let $G: \{0,1\}^s \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ be a pseudorandom generator (PRG). Are the following PRGs?
>
> 1. $G'(x) = G(x)_{0,\ldots,n-2}$ ($G'(x)$ drops the last bit of $G(x)$)
> 2. $G'(x) = G(x) \oplus 1^n$ ($\oplus$ is XOR)

Apparently, 1. is PRG because existence of a distinguisher for $G'$ implies existence of a distinguisher for $G$. However, if expansion factor of $G$ is $n = \ell(s)=s+1 > s$, then expansion factor of $G'$ is $\ell'(s) = \ell(s)-1=s$, so $\ell'(s) > s$ is not true, so $G'$ can't possibly be a PRG in this case, because it deosn't satisfy the expansion property. If I'm wrong, then why?

I'm not sure about 2., but I think it is a PRG, but I don't know how to prove it. Sketch of my proof: assume $G'$ isn't a PRG, then there exists an efficient distinguisher $D$ so that

$$|P_{r \leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D(r)=1]-P_{x \leftarrow\{0,1\}^s}[D(G'(x))=1]| > \text{negl}(n)$$

Then

$$|P_{r \leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D(r)=1]-P_{x \leftarrow\{0,1\}^s}[D(G(x) \oplus 1^n)=1]| > \text{negl}(n)$$

Now, I want to have that $P_{x \leftarrow\{0,1\}^s}[D(G(x) \oplus 1^n)=1] = P_{x \leftarrow\{0,1\}^s}[D(G(x))=1]$, so the proof is complete, but I don't know how to prove that equation. Intuitevely, $G(x) \oplus 1^n$ just flips all bits of $G(x)$, so if $G(x)$ appears random for $D$, then $G(x) \oplus 1^n$ should appear random too. Is there a formal (and preferably simple) way to show this?

Comment: In 1: Things can depend on exactly what definition of a PRG you use. With your's (unstated), is there anything wrong with: $G'$ is a PRG, but one with a lesser expansion factor than $G$? In 2: Try to use the fact that $G'(x) = G(x) \oplus 1^n\implies G(x) = G'(x) \oplus 1^n$.

Comment: Definition 3.14 from "Introduction to Modern Cryptography" https://i.imgur.com/yUBhqHk.png

Comment: Thanks for the hint for 2. So, assuming there is a distinguisher $D'$ for $G'$, we can construct distinguisher $D(y)$ for $G$  that outputs $0 \Leftrightarrow D'(y \oplus 1^n) = D'(G'(x)) = 0$, so $G$ is not a PRG, therefore our assumption is incorrect, so $G'$ is PRG. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you nailed 2. For 1: with your definition, my reading is that $G′$ is a PRG, but one with a lesser expansion factor than $G$.

Comment: But what if expansion factor of $G(s)$ is $|s| + 1$? It is perfectly fine PRG, but then expansion factor of $G'(s)$ is $(|s|+1)-1=|s|$ which is obviously not bigger than $|s|$, but equal, so it doesn't satisfy the expansion condition. Isn't this counterexample a problem here (that is, $G'$ may be PRG for almost all possible $G$s, but there is at least one for which it's not, so it is generally not true)? What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, your $G$ is a PRG such that $G'(x) = G(x)_{0,\ldots,n-2}$ is not a PRG, by your definition.